# How to bind datatable value to checkbox and combobox value?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, combobox

In Old Ver. of My code I am binding

```
 dgvShow.Columns["grdTest_Active"].DataPropertyName = oDTList.Columns["STATUS"].ToString();
 dgvShow.Columns["grdTest_LnkOrder"].DataPropertyName = oDTList.Columns["ORDER"].ToString();
```

I am converting the code in WPF and I have taken a grid and in that I have placed

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Active" Width="50"  IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox x:Name="chkActive" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Active}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="True"/>
    </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Order" Width="60"  IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Order}" />
     </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

when I am using

```
DataGridObjectTypeList.DataContext = oDTList.DefaultView;
```

on vmUCObjType Cs file It is binding the grid but, checkbox and combobox data is not showing.

I want to bind oDTList datatable value to my checkbox and combobox how to do that?

Please some one help me I am new in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed `ComboBoxColumn` and added `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in front end and in code behind I have done something like this:

```
((DataGridComboBoxColumn)dgShowList.Columns[1]).ItemsSource = DTCount.DefaultView;
((DataGridComboBoxColumn)dgShowList.Columns[1]).DisplayMemberPath = DTCount.Columns["Order"].ToString();
((DataGridComboBoxColumn)dgShowList.Columns[1]).SelectedValuePath = DTCount.Columns["Order"].ToString();
((DataGridComboBoxColumn)dgShowList.Columns[1]).SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Order");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your XAML file, write

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Name_ComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="id"/>
```

In your code behind, put:

```
Name_ComboBox.ItemSource = Table_name;
```

(Table_name being a reference to the table you mentioned).

then you can reach the id of the currently selected person in the combo box using the expression:

```
Name_ComboBox.SelectedValue
```

Comment: and what about the checkbox? what should I do the show check/uncheck of checkboxs